# Limited prep space, left food scale in microwave

Tags: microwave, kitchen-safety

I currently have limited room and I was making a recipe I had no other room but in my microwave to prep. I forgot the scale was in there and turned my microwave on. Will it be harmful health wise like any toxic chemical exposure? And will it ruin my microwave? The food scale is definitely a goner.

Comment: I can’t help with the main questions, but when I had an apartment with closets larger than the kitchen, I used a cutting board that would span the sink to get more room. (Mind you, the sink was so tiny a dinner plate couldn’t fit flat in it).  And sometimes I used the table just outside the kitchen.

Comment: And somewhere on here is a question on here about a possibly damaged microwave, and someone replied who said they were a professional engineer who dealt with microwaves, but I’m not finding it.  The only one I found about ruined microwaves has two majorly conflicting answers

Comment: How long did you run it for?

Comment: did you see any sparking/smell smoke or burning?